# Prove using axioms : Let x be an integer. If $x*x=x$, then $x = 0$ or $1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I have to prove this proposition using axioms for integers for my math class.
Is it enough to prove that if $x \cdot x = x$ and $x \neq 0$, then $x = 1$?

So far I have:

$x \cdot x = x$     by given proposition

$x = x  \cdot  1$   by Multiplication Identity

$x \cdot x = x  \cdot  1$ by Substitution

$x = 1$ by Cancellation

Comment: Looks OK, assuming you are allowed to use the reasons you capitalized. You should add to the last assertion what you know that allows you to cancel.

Comment: Ok, so I am allowed to change the proposition and prove it a different way, as long as they are logically equivalent? Like I did above?

Comment: You can seperate the cases. $x\cdot x=x$ is obvoiusly true for $x=0$. So you can rule that out and let $x\neq 0$ and then show, that $x=1$. What do you mean by "axioms for integers", by the way? Do you mean field axioms?

Comment: Integers are a ring but not a field

Answer (score 2):

Have you learned that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field? If so:

**Claim:**

Any subring of a field $F$ is an integral domain ($ab= 0 \implies a = 0 \lor b= 0)$.

**Proof:**

Let $R$ be a subring of a field $F$. Suppose $a , b \in R$ and that $ab = 0$.

Then since $F$ is a field and assuming $a \neq 0$, $a$ has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$ in $F$.

We get $0_R = 0_F = a^{-1}(ab) =_F (a^{-1}a)b =_F 1*b =_R b $ where the last equality is true in $R$ due to $R$ being a subring. $\blacksquare$

Next check that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ be with $x^2 = x$.

We get $x^2 - x = 0$ and so $x(x-1) = 0$. By the claim either $x = 0$ or $x =1$.

Comment: If the downvoter would explain, I'd be happy to address any issues..